# Is there a sequence of natural numbers with these properties?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Is there a sequence of natural numbers (except 1) which every consecutive term is $\textbf{not}$ relatively prime and each natural number appears $\textbf{exactly once}$?

Comment: What should be the successor of $1$ in that sequence?

Comment: @MartinR except 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with $a_1=2$ and for $n\geq 2$ let $a_{n}$ be the smallest number not already used which shares a factor with $a_{n-1}$. 
$$2, 4, 6, 3, 9, 12, 8, 10, 5, 15, 18, 14, 7, 21, 24, 16,\dots$$
Prove that every integer number greater than $1$ appears exactly once.

This is called the [EKG sequence](http://oeis.org/A064413). A proof that this sequence is a permutation of $\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$ is given in ["The EKG Sequence"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204011.pdf) by J. C. Lagarias, E. M. Rains and N. J. A. Sloane.

Comment: If someone wants to read the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204011.pdf.

Comment: @MartinR Useful reference!! Thanks.

Comment: You could add it to your answer, comments may be deleted.

Comment: @MartinR Done. Thanks again.

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks

Comment: @MartinR awesome!

Comment: Very interesting. Not so simple that every $n>1$ appears  in the sequence. The proof in the link develops 4 lemmas and then a proof using all 4 of them.