# Sequence of positive integers, $a_{n+1}$ is equal to the smallest positive integer which hasn't appeared and is noncoprime with $a_n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Consider a sequence of positive integers $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ such that $a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, a_{n+1}$ is equal to the smallest positive integer which has not yet occurred in the sequence and is not coprime with $a_n$. Prove that all positive integers appear in this sequence.

Ideas: Suppose the contrary, and let $m$ be the smallest number which does not occur in the sequence. Consider a prime which divides $m$, say $p$. Then consider a sufficiently large $M$ such that $1,2 \ldots m-1$ have all occurred in the sequence up until $a_{M}$. Then no other multiple of $p$ may occur in the sequence afterwards, otherwise let $a_j = pk$, then $a_{j+1} = m$, contradiction.

From here on I'm not sure how to continue. However I have noticed that $m$ does not necessarily have to be the smallest, and it can be any such that it does not appear, and we may use an analogous argument, combining with the previous argument, to prove that eventually every prime $p$ stops occurring in the sequence at some point. However I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: This sequence is called the [EKG sequence](https://oeis.org/A064413), and there's a lot of material that can be found about it. Related note: trying to look up a newly encountered integer sequence on the OEIS is always a good idea.

Comment: And once you know the name of that sequence, you can search on this site and find https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3137275/42969

Comment: @MartinR If the answer shows that the given sequence does the job, then yes. Is this the case ?

Comment: It links to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204011.pdf), whose Sec. $2$ proves it over a couple of pages.

Comment: @Peter: The definition of the sequence in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3137275/42969 is identical to the definition of this sequence, apart from the initial $a_1 = 1$. And the answer contains a link to an article with the proof of that every integer occurs exactly once.

Comment: @Peter: On the other hand, a (sketch of) the proof, posted as an answer on this site, would be useful IMO, instead of having that link only. Then one could discuss if that should be posted as an answer here (because this question specifically asks for the proof), or as an additional answer to the older question (which asks for the existence of such a sequence only) ...

Comment: @Peter@MartinR Thank you! I've read the proof and it is exactly what I was looking for.